# Rails Griddler-ses causing dependancy issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, griddler

I added the griddler and griddler-ses gem to my rails project and now I am getting this error. When I remove the griddler-ses gem the error goes away.

```
stack.rb:108:in `assert_index': No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::ParamsParser (RuntimeError)
```

here is my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'sinatra', '2.0.0.beta2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.2.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'faker'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'skeleton-rails'
gem 'griddler'
gem 'griddler-ses'
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the pull requests and issues on the [griddler-ses GitHub page](https://github.com/85x14/griddler-ses), it currently doesn't support Rails 5.

You may want to log this as an issue there, as the gem will need to be updated to account for [the change to ParamsParser in Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/38d2bf5fd1f3e014f2397898d371c339baa627b1).